# Not able to access request parameters in java servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I am using same dpPost method for two different form data. I am not able to access request parameters for second form.

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   if("schema".equals(session.getAttribute("which"))) {
             second_html();
             //call second page here
             }

             String btnClicked= request.getParameter("p2"); // This is getting null after submitting second_html()
       if("edit".equals(session.getAttribute("which"))){
     /*   process second page here after Submit on the second page
                   I am trying to access request.getParameter() but value is null                  here for the fields in the second page       */
                 second_html();
    }
   }
  first_html() {
   // have form and submit button
   session.setAttribute("which","schema");

}
second_html() {
 // have form and submit button
  <input type='text' name='p2' id='p2' size='3' >
 session.setAttribute("which","edit");
}
```

EDIT : My session getters are working fine. But the request.getParameter is not working.

Comment: `I am not able to access request parameters for second form`. Quite unclear. Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing session variables, not your request parameters.

You can access them using

```
request.getParameter("which")
```

Comment: of course it is not. You asked how to access request parameters, we gave you an answer. Please ask more precisely.

Comment: how to access p2 . I am getting null in request.getParameter("p2")

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you should be using [`ServletRequest.getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29),

```
String v = request.getParameter("which");
if (v.equals("schema")) {

} else if (v.equals("edit")) {

}
```

Comment: Clearly then `submit` isn't a request parameter. If your question is not about session, then why is that the code you posted?

Comment: submit is the parameter. I posted the code because I thought because of this code structure there is problem in getting the request parameter.

Comment: What value do you think this submit parameter has? Are you mixing a GET url with a POST form?